# Is it possible to override hibernate.jdbc.batch_size in Grails hibernate plugin?

Tags: hibernate, grails

Is it possible to override hibernate.jdbc.batch_size in Grails hibernate plugin? (Grails 2.4.x/hibernate 3)

If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/2.4.3/guide/hibernate.html) you'll see that you can create the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file in your `grails-app/conf/hibernate` directory.

Once you have that file you can configure hibernate however you like. Which includes setting the batch size: `<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</property>`